# How to make Unity sprite animation not lerp?

Tags: unity, animation, sprites

I set sprite animation at key1 and key2.

at Key1 :

```
Position.x = 0
```

at Key2 :

```
Position.x = 1
```

I want it not lerping. i mean i want it appear at posX 0 and posX 1. not between 0~1.

what should i do?

Comment: What do you mean by lerping?

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe I believe they're refering to "Linear intERPolation". As in, having a curve instead of a square.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe I mean i want it move in discrete way, not continuous way. and Mailerdaimon's answer solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to rightclick on the animation curve and set both `tangents` to `broken` and `constant`.
[image]

[image]

See the documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingCurves.html